# Установка убунту 10.10 на виртуальную машину.

Tags: ubuntu

```
Я - ламер,пытаюсь поставить на виртуальную машину ubuntu 10.10 для нетбуков.
```

Вопрос состоит  в следующем: Как определить корневую файловую систему, если в точке монтирования нет root'а?     В точке монтирования предлагаются такие катологи, как: /boot, /home, /tmp, /var, /usr,/srv, /opt, /usr/local.И как вообще лучше заполнить таблицу разделов на 8 гб?

Answer (score 1):

1. Не называй себя ламером никогда. Никогда.
2. Нет точки монтирования "root". Обычно под этим имеется "голая" метка вида "/". Исходя из текста, преположу что ставишь в виртуалбоксе. На первый раз пусть установщик поможет сделать большую часть работы и сам выберет разбиение диска. А так то-видеозаписи -http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMs2yG_1D7E - тысячи их в сети.

Answer (score 0):

/boot, /home, /tmp, /var, /usr,/srv, /opt, /usr/local

все находятся в root

Root  в переводе на русский - корень, имеется ввиду древовидная структура директорий и файлов (директории назвали папками в лавке микрософт, в переводе на русский файл - папка)

Answer (score 0):

Ставьте корень "/" и не парьтесь. Если поставите что-нибудь другое, не найдёте потом! Каталог /boot, как я понимаю, создан для установки других гнусовместимых осей, если он расположен на отдельном разделе. В смысле, гну-совместимых! Гнусо-вместимые не обсуждаем!  На 10.10 стоит второй граб, который отлично грузит всё, что видит. Сам на этом сижу. А у меня на убунте каталог /root лежит в /home/root/. Для юзерофильных целей. А в корне - логическая сцыль.